# How to retrieve App Service Plan instance name (RDXXXXX)?

Tags: azure, azure-rm, azure-rest-api, az, azure-service-plan

I am having an issue trying to retrieve all the instance names in an Azure App Service Plan.

In Azure Monitor, if you specify a "Scope" to "App Service Plan" and look at the Metric "CPU Percentage" and then add a filter to specify the "Instance" property, you can see which instance uses the most CPU.  I am trying to do a PowerShell script to get these values.  Unfortunatly I have not found any Azure REST Api that would give me this information so that my script would be 100% dynamic.  I looked at the AzureRm or Az PowerShell modules but did not find anything there.

Any ideas how I can retrieve this list?  The instances names looks like this :RD123456.

Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you want to get the web instance name, if that's right you could get it from instance process with [Web Apps - Get Instance Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/getinstanceprocess).

And under the `environment_variables` there is a `COMPUTERNAME` suppose this is what you want.

[image]

Comment: is not it the same thing answered below?

Comment: Check the rest description, it's not same thing.

Comment: @Sajeetharan,what you give is list app plan and what I give is Get Instance Process. And did you check my picture content?

Comment: check the comment below, I have mentioned he needs to use List to get all instances and get method to get the name

Comment: @Sajeetharan,Did you try your get method? Yours is this [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/appserviceplans/get) and check again what's mine. One is plan get and one is web instance get. If you insist they are same, I have nothing to say.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser.  I remember trying this out but the values where all nulls.  I will give it a try with another account and let you guys know.  It seems to be what I am looking for.

Comment: I actually tested this solution before without success (the environment variable was empty). I investigated and it seems that the account I was using did not have enough rights to view the environment variables.  Using a contributor account worked.  I will take a look at which authorization would be necessary other than "Contibutor"

Comment: After further testing, the "Contributor" role is necessary in order to be able to read Environment_Variables properties.  Otherwise, the values will be empty in the property.  Hope this helps.